# MySQL Remote connection in CentOS 8

Tags: mysql

I have a CentOS 8 server(Server-1) with mysql Server version: 8.0.21 Source distribution with default installation.

I am trying to connect to this mysql server from another server. (Say server-2).

In my CentOS 8 server I can find only below three conf file in folder /etc/my.cnf.d/.

client.cnf  mysql-default-authentication-plugin.cnf  mysql-server.cnf

As searched to connect to this server from remote sever I need to enable below line in my.cnf

bind-address           = 0.0.0.0

But my.cnf is as shown below.

[client-server]
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

In short i am confused with this mysql-8 configuration in CentOS 8. Where is bind-address directive located in ? Where is my mysql other configuration located in ?

Help me guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you install WHM/cPanel over it

This will be easy because it have a option for it.

And you can have a trail license of the WHM/cPanel if you are resolving with the money.

you can find more over here

https://docs.cpanel.net/installation-guide/install/

hope it may help you.

Thanks

@The next level coders

Comment: No...I Cant use WHM/CPanel